Cannot define variables in TS file with input elements from HTML
I'm trying to run a ts/js file from a button in an HTML file.
I'm using TS and node js.
this is a bit of code where I get the error
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const saftbutton = document.getElementById('xbutton') as HTMLButtonElement;


    xbutton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const startdateInput = document.getElementById('startdate') as HTMLInputElement;
            const enddateInput = document.getElementById('enddate') as HTMLInputElement;

            const startDate = startdateInput.value;
                    const endDate = enddateInput.value;

            console.log('Start Date:', startDate);
            console.log('End Date: ', endDate);

            const response = await fetch('/prog/callback',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:
                    {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        startDate,
                        endDate
                    })
                }
            );
            await start(2);

and this is the error I get:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Remember to defer your script on the HTML side. <script src="..." async defer></script> instead of using an event listener. By the time a deferred script runs the document is, by definition, ready to work with.

How is this code running? While others seem to assume it's loaded in a <script> tag, this code at the moment is running in node.js, where there's no document (or window). As code generally looks the same, depending on what you're trying to achieve and how, it may be easy to mix up what stays on server side (node.js), and what gets served to the browser (where there's a window, and document in it). Are you following some tutorial? This excerpt in itself is not enough to tell what's happening exactly. Also, there's nothing typescript here at the moment.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's a node.js error message, with the ^ and the empty line after, just the stack trace was cut down. Also, the document object itself is available in the browser by the time anything JS gets to run, only the content may be missing.

thank you both. I'm not following any tutorial. this is my first time using typescript and node js. @tevemadar, you're right and I didn't know it made a difference if the code ran. the code is in a .TS file and I made an html file where the user inputs the start and end dates and clicks a button to run the code.

Why is this code running in Node, though, if it's on-page code?

well, it's not on-page code. it is an app to get data from API, store in db and spit out an XML... I just wanted to add an html to help non technical users

That's what I'm asking: why is this code running in node if it's meant to be page code for that html file? Normally you put page code in its own file or files (even if you transpile and/or bundle that separately) because that code has to run in the browser, not Node. You don't make it part of your server-side code, and you don't run it with Node.

You would want to attach onto window, because document may not be ready until DOMContentLoaded is fired:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// whatever you want
});


Which is why you don't do this, you load your script with the defer attribute, which has been around for ever a decade now =)
